# OnEdit trigger fired simultaneously causing wrong calculation of last row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm new to Google App Script and trying to create a queue-like spreadsheet.
The current design is that: in sheet A, there's a column of checkboxs, and if any one of them is checked, the entire row would be moved to the end of another sheet, say sheet B.

The way I calculate the end of the sheet B is as followed:
(I read from a different stackoverflow post)

```
var Avals = dest.getRange("B:B").getValues();
var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
var lastRow = String(Alast + 1);
```

The issue I'm having here is that when I check two checkboxes quickly one by one, they are mapped to the same lastRow in sheet B, because the second checkbox triggers the onEdit trigger before the first one has moved the entire row to the bottom of the sheet B.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Right now, the workaround is since it's a shared google sheet, I asked my colleagues not to click the checkbox column at the same time.

Comment: Would hiding the row from the first `sheet A` be satisfactory, vs deleting it? It could still be shown on `Sheet B` once checked.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for what little testing I've done

```
function onEdit(e) {
  LockService.getScriptLock().tryLock(2000)
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    let tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1 , vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  }
  LockService.getScriptLock().releaseLock();
}
```